# Is there a way to Link a SQL Server Login to a specific port on which its listening?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am exploring options to determine if there any way of linking a particular SQL Server Login to a specific port. To be more precise, I have SQL Server listening on 2 ports and I want a particular port to be accessible to only one login. Is this any way we can achieve this?

I have this SQL Server running on an Azure VM, and this will be accessed using an end point. Please advise.

Comment: Check this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191220.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 Basically: GRANT | DENY | REVOKE CONNECT ON ENDPOINT Not sure whether you can do it with Azure however.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you for your response. This link helped me with the following solution. This what I did:

1. Configured the SQL Server to listen on a different port other than the default.
2. Created a new TCP End Point, and linked this endpoint to the new port. 
3. Gave access to this endpoint only to a specific login.

Import point to note: Creating a new TCP endpoint will revoke access to the PUBLIC group on other default TCP endpoints. So need to plan accordingly.